# Does "building effectiveness" affect all manageable structures?

Tags: tropico-5

Some [managers](http://tropico.wikia.com/wiki/Manager) will raise the "effectiveness" of a building. Do all buildings (that can have a manager) benefit from this stat?

`Foreman:   Effectiveness increased and job quality reduced by 10 (Max 20)`

I get that a production facility, like a ranch or a steel mill, will run more efficiently with a higher effectiveness (e.g. produce more goods). But what about a service facility, such as a Dock, teamster's office, etc? Do the tiny trucks move faster,  or collect more goods in a run?

Am I wasting the the Foreman's skill on a service facility,  and just lowering their job quality? Or does it somehow make them more efficient?

Comment: Anecdotally I would say yes, based on my own observation, but then again Tropico's simulation is quite opaque, and I find that micromanagement doesn't seem to help much.

Comment: @PrivatePansy agreed on all accounts. i did recently test and see that raising the effectiveness of a clinic with a manager directly raises the quality of the healthcare provided, and I'd consider that a service structure. The docks/teamsters/construction offices dont have a stat to test against though, so I'm still curious about those, and others like them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any building that has "effectiveness" will benefit from increasing it. Crops/farms produce more, factories produce more goods with the some input of raw materials, construction offices build faster, teamsters move more/faster, and docks decrease the amount of time between ships the higher the effectiveness.

Unless you have a job shortage, the foreman manager is a catch-22. He increases effectiveness but decreases job quality. If the job quality drops enough, workers will leave for other jobs. If you don't have a full work force, effectiveness drops.

Comment: The foreman works well if you have other buffs increasing job quality beyond where it needs to be.